# Highlight countries on map using PHP

Tags: php, dictionary

I've seen this question asked all over the net, but haven't seen an answer that solves it yet.

Here's what I need to do - based on data from my database, I need to highlight countries on a map of Africa. This is for a web-based game and I don't want to use Google Maps and the like.

This can't be a new problem and I assume there's a PHP library somewhere out there that does it, or at least a file containing the necessary info (from what I understand I need a lot of coordinates). The map doesn't need to be interactive (no on-click or on-hover events) and I'd like to keep this server-side if possible. It just needs to display the countries and color them based on data from the database.

However, if you don't have a PHP solution, I'll be grateful for any alternative options using Javascript (note that data still has to be extracted from DB).

One last question - how hard would it be to simply create a .PNG image of each country with the rest of the map transparent and position them so as to form a map? In that case, is there a PHP function that would allow me to highlight individual countries?

Comment: Great! You have the spec, now what have you tried?

Comment: What I haven't tried is plotting the map points myself because I don't want to spend the next month doing it. I've tried searching the internet for working solutions. What I haven't found is an answer, but what I have found is a hundred people whose only contribution to the various threads is an irritating semi-funny sarcastic remark. Thank you very much for being no. 101.

Comment: Given that you are working with a map, have you considered using Flash + ActionScript? Actionscript can talk to PHP via JavaScript. And PHP can also talk to Actionscript. That way you can highlight map elements in Flash given user actions in PHP, and fire actions in PHP based on user interactions with the map.

Comment: Thanks barista, but I've never worked with Flash and don't really want to start now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this easily in PHP but with a jQuery plugin imageMapster it's really simple. Here's a map demo that sounds suitable for you.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/examples/usa.html

You can set it up as an image map and set it to highlight map areas on load, mouseover, click etc. The highlight can be either CSS based or an alternate image.

It's very well documented and has been a life saver many times for me.

Here's an example of how you set area to their onstate:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#IMAGE_NAME').mapster('set',true,'AREA_ID');
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** This is actually the 2nd time today I've recommended this. I'm not affiliated with it in any way, I just think it's cool.

Comment: No worries. If it's your accepted answer don't forget to flag it as the answer. It'll help you get more answers in the future and helps my site rep out. Ta.

Comment: Flagged, thank you. One more thing - if I decide to use on-click events after all, do you think I could use Ajax to send some data to a PHP script? Basically, I'd just need to save the name/id associated with the territory that was clicked.

Comment: Ta. You can add onClick events to each image map area so you can get it to do what ever you want. Each area will have a unique ID so just tie that in with your DB and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

[VectorWorkz GeoChart](http://vectorworkz.com/products/geochart/features) is a kind of jQuery plugin which allows you to change the colors of map regions based on data from database, it also allows you to bound the database data to the regions, so that colors of the map regions will automatically change when the bounded data value changes.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you'll have to trace each country with some sort of image map or SVG tool and map all of the points. That should  take a while - when you're done with that, then you can probably use HTML's canvas tag to composite the points into a polygon over the image.

Comment: You can do it in Fireworks fairly quickly and then export it and take the coordinates from the HTML it gives you.

Comment: Thanks. One SVG tool I found that looks like I could use it is mapper.js (http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/). Any info on this?